# How to force Margin-left (marginStart) to image in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a statistic/history screen in my app, which shows the last 7 days history of user's activity. I've been using 7 fragments on the same screen to represent each day (7 days ago, 6 days ago....).
On each fragment there is an image which should be changed, regarding the condition.
The problem is that I cannot margin the images on the fragments to the left side. They are all centered somehow. I need you kind help to solve it

This is the layout of the "History.java" which contains the frameLayouts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:background="#E0E1FF"
    tools:context=".controller.History">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_7_days_ago"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="85dp">

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_6_days_ago"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="85dp">

    </FrameLayout>  // ... below are all the same, 5 days ago, 4 etc...
```

This is one of the fragments layout (which is similar to the rest of them).
The first ImageView below (no_color) image, is the one I would like to force to the left in each fragment.  This image is replaced with condition by using 
colorBar.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_color);
The color are changing well, but the image is always centered

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".controller.History"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/color_bar_image_7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/no_color"
    android:contentDescription="fragment_layout_7_days_ago" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_7_days_ago_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:text="@string/_7_days_ago" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_7_days_ago_comment_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="250dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/view_comment_btn"
        android:onClick="comment7DaysAgo"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_comment_black_48px" />
</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

UPDATE:
I forgot to mention that each fragment is called to replace the frame of that day, by:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_7_days_ago, new StatisticSevenDaysAgo()).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am alittle unsure about how exactly the final result is supposed to look, there could be some problems with the relativeLayout having height and width match_paret. But changing framelayout to linearlayout with orientation horizontal should do the trick for the image alignment.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".controller.History"
android:layout_marginStart="0dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/color_bar_image_7"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/no_color"
    android:contentDescription="fragment_layout_7_days_ago" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_7_days_ago_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:text="@string/_7_days_ago" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_7_days_ago_comment_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="250dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/view_comment_btn"
        android:onClick="comment7DaysAgo"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_comment_black_48px" />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, i tried to do it, but it didn't work.
Here is a link to how it looks like: (you can see that all colored images are centered instead of being marged to the left
https://ibb.co/hyXk531

Comment: edited my answer. the height and width of the imageview cannot be match_parent.

Comment: still nothing happens. I'm thinking of using in my code FrameLayout.LayoutParams disapp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(700, 300);  it seems to work

Comment: if nothing happends hten either you didnt copy the code i pasted, or you have some logic that is changing the layout, cause in the designer this xml gives you a 60x60 image aligned to the left of the text.

Comment: I do have some logic that is changing in the layout. probably it is the reason why it became complicated.
Anyway, I really appreciate your help, because it helped me to solve other problem that I had (-: